# change ftp_get download directory

Tags: php

I am using the below code to download using ftp

```
$local_file = $_GET['u'];
$server_file = $_GET['u'];
    $ftp_host = '';
    $ftp_user_name = '';
    $ftp_user_pass = '';


$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_host) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_host");
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
ftp_pasv($ftp_conn,true);
ftp_chdir($ftp_conn, '');
$file_list = ftp_nlist($ftp_conn, ".");
//var_dump($file_list);
//var_dump(ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY));
if (ftp_get($ftp_conn, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
echo "Successfully written to $local_file\n";
}
else {
    echo "There was a problem\n";
}
```

am getting successfully written to filename but i cant seem to find the file on my computer. Do you if i can change where the file is being downloaded to.

Comment: check at the path of the local file

Comment: if you mean localhost i found nothing there

Comment: Check where the *php file* (which contains your code!) is located.

Comment: @SergiPasoev i found the file there but what i need is to download that file to my harddrive

Answer (score 2):

Pass an absolute path (instead of `"myfile.txt"` try `"/home/user/path/to/yourfile.txt"`)